# Finding correct xpath

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I want to find from the [page](http://gepris.dfg.de/gepris/institution/5000) the correct xpath for the string

"**Untersuchung polymerischer Stabilsation in kolloidalen Systemen unter Verwendung neuartiger feldtheoretischer Simulationen**" for one item and the other item of string is **"Entwicklung hämatopoietischer Stammzellen aus humanen ES- und iPS-Zellen"**

```
name = 'lianjia'
allowed_domains = ["gepris.dfg.de/gepris/"]
start_urls =['http://gepris.dfg.de/gepris/institution/5000', 'http://gepris.dfg.de/gepris/institution/5008']
My Scrapy program is
    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath("//div[@id='detailseite']"):        
            lianjia = lianjiaItem()
            lianjia['item1'] = sel.xpath("").extract()
            lianjia['item2'] = sel.xpath("").extract()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lianjia['item1'] = sel.xpath("//li[@id=4]/ul/li/ul/li[1]/div/div/a/text()").extract()
lianjia['item2'] = sel.xpath("//li[@id=4]/ul/li/ul/li[2]/div/div/a/text()").extract()
```

Comment: Add more description/supporting content  to support your answer.